# centering text vertically in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I would like to center the text on my homepage vertical in the middel of the page. Right now i tried to do this with a percentage, but this isn't the right way because when i open the webpage on my phone or an ipad the text doesn't center. Does anyone know how i can center it the right way?

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
 background: white;
}

html, body{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height:100%;
}

/* wrapper */
#wrapper {
 min-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

/* menu */
#header {
    height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
    background: #000000;
}

li {
 display: block;
    float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

a {
 position: reletive;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
}

li:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
}
 
.home {
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.contact {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 30px;
}

/*content*/
#content {
 padding-bottom:80px;
}

/* homepage */
.anouk {
 font-family: 'Oswald';
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 80px;
 text-align: center; 
 margin-top: 15%;
}


/* footer */
#footer {
 background: #000000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.icoontjes {
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 height: 50px;
}

.icoontjes:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Anouk</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
        <div class="menu">
          <!--Home-->
          <li class="home">
            <a href="index.html">
            Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <!--Over Mij-->
          <li class="over">
            <a href="over.html">
            Over Mij
            </a>
          </li>
          <!--Portfolio-->
          <li class="portfolio">
            <a href="portfolio.html">
            Portfolio
            </a>
          </li>
          <!--Contact-->
          <li class="contact">
            <a href="contact.html">
            Contact
            </a>
          </li>                    
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content"> 
        <p class="anouk">
        Anouk Den Haag
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <a href="mailto:#">
          <img class="icoontjes" src="icoontjes/email.png" alt="email">
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <img class="#" src="icoontjes/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img class="icoontjes" src="icoontjes/instagram.png" alt="instagram">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display` offers you 2 options : the table layout or the flex model ( both will push footer down if content grows)

---

*test snippets in full page mode and resize window*

---

1) `display`:table/table-row/table-cell (should include IE8 and older browsers CSS 2.1)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  background: white;
}

html,
body,
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}


/* wrapper */

#wrapper {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}


/* menu */

#header {
  height: 80px;
  display: table-row;
  background: #000000;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

a {
  position: reletive;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
}

li:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.home {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.contact {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}


/*content*/

#content {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}


/* homepage */

.anouk {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* footer */

#footer {
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: table-row;
  text-align: center;
}

.icoontjes {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}

.icoontjes:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Anouk</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
        <div class="menu">
          <!--Home-->
          <li class="home">
            <a href="index.html">
            Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <!--Over Mij-->
          <li class="over">
            <a href="over.html">
            Over Mij
            </a>
          </li>
          <!--Portfolio-->
          <li class="portfolio">
            <a href="portfolio.html">
            Portfolio
            </a>
          </li>
          <!--Contact-->
          <li class="contact">
            <a href="contact.html">
            Contact
            </a>
          </li>                    
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content"> 
        <p class="anouk">
        Anouk Den Haag
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <a href="mailto:#">
          <img class="icoontjes" src="icoontjes/email.png" alt="email">
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <img class="#" src="icoontjes/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img class="icoontjes" src="icoontjes/instagram.png" alt="instagram">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </body>
</html>
```

---

2) the flex model (latest browsers)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  background: white;
}

html,
body,
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}


/* wrapper */

#wrapper, #content {
  display: flex;/* triiger flex model prefixed might be needed for not so old browsers */
  flex-direction:column /* here we need to stack elements */
}


/* menu */

#header {
  height: 80px;
  background: #000000;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

a {
  position: reletive;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
}

li:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.home {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.contact {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}


/*content*/

#content {
  flex:1;/* take as much space avalaible */
  justify-content:center;/* because it is display:flex too, you can horizontally center its contents */
  align-items:center;/* because it is display:flex too, you can vertically center its contents */
}


/* homepage */

.anouk {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* footer */

#footer {
  background: #000000;
  height: 80px;
  text-align:center;
}

.icoontjes {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}

.icoontjes:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Anouk</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
        <div class="menu">
          <!--Home-->
          <li class="home">
            <a href="index.html">
            Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <!--Over Mij-->
          <li class="over">
            <a href="over.html">
            Over Mij
            </a>
          </li>
          <!--Portfolio-->
          <li class="portfolio">
            <a href="portfolio.html">
            Portfolio
            </a>
          </li>
          <!--Contact-->
          <li class="contact">
            <a href="contact.html">
            Contact
            </a>
          </li>                    
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content"> 
        <p class="anouk">
        Anouk Den Haag
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <a href="mailto:#">
          <img class="icoontjes" src="icoontjes/email.png" alt="email">
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <img class="#" src="icoontjes/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img class="icoontjes" src="icoontjes/instagram.png" alt="instagram">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </body>
</html>
```

add overflow:auto to `#content` and it will show a scrollbar if needed , so footer is not pushed down.

Comment: I tried the second option and it worked perfectly when I tried it in the browser. But when I upload it it stops working and the text went up when the screen got smaller. Do you know how this is possible since it is the exact same code. (I tested it in multiple browser but they all gave the samen result)

Comment: I am sorry it is fully working now. For some reason my old CSS file was stuck on the server so my new file didn't work but i want to thank you for your help!

Comment: @Anoux geen probleme, glad i helped . this tutorial might help you to go a little further https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS to the text you want centered:

```
.your_centered_element {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

This will keep the element centered.

Read about the `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does kind of work but the text is a little bit out of the middle. (i did remove the margin) do you know how this is posible?

Comment: Is your `.anouk` in your `#content`? @Anoux

Comment: @Anoux Try taking it out

Comment: Try adding ` margin:0;` to your `.Anouk` @Anoux

Answer (score 0):

One solution here is to use `viewport-width` and `viewport-height` units:

```
.anouk {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
line-height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for centering the text you have to use **margin auto**
css file--

* {
    border: 1px dashed black;
}

div >p {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FFD700;
    margin: auto;
}

  html code 
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet3.css"/>
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><p >
        Anouk Den Haag
        </p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

SEE THE SNAPSHOT [image]